# Javascript show multiple table rows from multiple select

Tags: javascript, multiple-select

I would like my code to show multiple table rows depending on what the user selects in the multiple select item. My code only shows the last selected item for some reason, could someone please help me? My code is:

```
if(List[x].selected)
{               
    $('table#newspaper-a tr:not(#header, #trWeekNummer)').hide();
    $('table#newspaper-a tr:not(#header, #trWeekNummer)').each(function(){      
        $('td:nth-child(1)',this).each(function(){  
            if($(this).text() == List[x].value)
                $(this).parent(this).show();
        });
    });     
}
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: How do I create a fiddle? I'm sorry, i'm just new here :)

Comment: You can go to jsfiddle.net. Paste you js, html and css in the relevant columns and hit save. Than post the link here.

Comment: I would like to do that but there are so many database connections in it that I'm going to put a stripped version in there.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fza4M/

It's a very stripped version of the real table but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem myself, the solution was:

```
$('table#newspaper-a tr:not(#header, #trWeekNummer)').hide();

if(List[x].selected)
{               
$('table#newspaper-a tr:not(#header, #trWeekNummer)').each(function(){      
    $('td:nth-child(1)',this).each(function(){  
        if($(this).text() == List[x].value)
            $(this).parent(this).show();
    });
});
```

}